# make throws error looking for boost libraries

Tags: c++, macos, boost, cmake

I am trying to compile a C++ project that uses Boost. I have tried this on a Windows machine (first trying with cygwin, then with Visual Studio) as well as a Macbook. I continue to run into the problem that `cmake` will find Boost just fine, but `make` will tell me that it can't find the first boost library it needs to look for. I've tried using `make -I/path/to/boost/parent/directory/` and the output is identical.

I've attached the Mac terminal output for `cmake ..` and `make` below. I'll also include the steps that I took, and attempts to dissect the problem:

1. Ran `brew install boost`
2. Ran `git clone git-repo`
3. Ran `mkdir build` `cmake ..` `make`

I have also reinstalled boost, reinstalled brew, and checked that the proper include paths were being used by the compiler. `CMakeLists.txt` has the line `find_package(Boost REQUIRED)`. Doing all these yields the same results shown below.

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

```
mudly@MyMac build % cmake ..

-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.76.0")  
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES) 
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES) 
-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FOUND OpenMP_CXX_FOUND) 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/mudly/source/matching/matching/build
```

```
mudly@MyMac build % make

[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/matching_distance_test.dir/tests/test_bifiltration.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/matching_distance_test.dir/tests/test_common.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/mudly/source/matching/matching/tests/test_common.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/mudly/source/matching/matching/include/matching_distance.h:19:
In file included from /Users/mudly/source/matching/matching/../bottleneck/include/bottleneck.h:41:
In file included from /Users/mudly/source/matching/matching/../bottleneck/include/bottleneck_detail.h:41:
In file included from /Users/mudly/source/matching/matching/../bottleneck/include/bound_match.h:36:
In file included from /Users/mudly/source/matching/matching/../bottleneck/include/neighb_oracle.h:37:
/Users/mudly/source/matching/matching/../bottleneck/include/dnn/geometry/euclidean-fixed.h:4:10: fatal error: 'boost/operators.hpp' file not found

#include <boost/operators.hpp>

         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/matching_distance_test.dir/tests/test_common.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/matching_distance_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: _"...using make -I/path/to/boost/..."_ this should be the parent directory of boost as `#include <boost/operators.hpp>` includes `boost/` in the name of the file to be included.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks for the note. I was a cavalier about editing out actual paths on my computer, but I did use the parent directory. I'll edit  the post to reflect a more accurate path

Comment: It might be helpful to look at the exact command used by `make` to invoke your compiler (make sure that the desired flags are there and that they match the directory structure on your system).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Adding the line `include_directories(/path/to/libraries/)` in the CMake file was enough.

Comment: In most cases `include_directories` is actually enough to resolve "file not found" compiler error. But what kind of help you expected from us, since we don't know the content of `CMakeLists.txt` except of its single line (`find_package(Boost REQUIRED)`)?